# Not detecting all the duplicates in an int array

Tags: java

After sorting an integer array `"arr"` I try to identify duplicates in the array.  It does that for part of the array, but it does not identify duplicates in the whole array.  I appreciate the help.  Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ex24 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, n = 100;
    Integer[] arr = Collections.nCopies(n, 0).toArray(new Integer[0]);
  //  int[] array = {0};
    for (int j = 0; j < n ; j++){
        arr[j] = (int) (Math.random() * 365 + 1);
    //    System.out.print(j + "   " + arr[j] + "\n");
    }
        Arrays.sort(arr);  //sort the arr
      //  String arrq = (Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println("\n");

        Duplicate(arr, n);
        } 
        static void Duplicate(Integer[] arr, int n) {
           int j = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i < n-1 ; i++) {

           if (arr[i] != arr[i+1]) {
                System.out.println(" at i   (" + i + ")    print arr[i] " + arr[i]); 
           }
                    else {
                    j = j +1;
                 System.out.println("  j =  " + j + "  at i (" + i + ")  arr[i] is double at date  " + arr[i]); 
           }                   
           }
        }
      }
```

Comment: I think this is a perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Please edit your post to get rid of lines which are irrelevant (the commented out lines) and to indent the code more readably. It would also help a lot if you could make your sample code include a specific collection which fails, rather than just using a random one.

Comment: Jon: What do you mean with "It would also help a lot if you could make your sample code include a specific collection which fails, rather than just using a random one."

Answer (score 1):

Since you're comparing Integer Objects so instead of:

```
if (arr[i] != arr[i+1])
```

do this:

```
if (!arr[i].equals(arr[i+1]))
```

Pls understand that `!=` or `==` operators are used for comparing primitives or for comparing Object references instead of comparing actual Object values.

btw your code needs some refactoring. If you really want to find duplicates there are some better ways to do that like using `java.util.Set` instead of Sorting the array to find duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're comparing `Integer` references using `==`. (Or rather, `!=`.)

The `==` and `!=` operators will always compare *references* when the operands are reference type expressions - they compare whether the two operands are references to the exact same object, rather than whether they refer to equal objects.

Boxing in Java is guaranteed to use a cache of `Integer` objects for values in the range -127 to 127 which is why you're seeing it work for *some* values. Beyond that (or some point<sup>1</sup>) you'll be seeing different `Integer` objects which won't compare as equal when simply compared by reference. You want to compare for *value* equality instead, with the `equals` method:

```
if (!arr[i].equals(arr[i+1]))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The exact boundary is implementation-specific: some implementations may have a larger cache.

Answer (score 0):

You comparing objects with `==` what is wrong.

```
if (arr[i] != arr[i+1]) {
```

Two ways to fix this particular issue with Integer:

1 .

```
if (!arr[i].equals(arr[i+1])) {
```

2 .

```
if (arr[i].intValue() != arr[i+1].intValue()) {
```

Comment: Thank you all..solution works fine..how would you do to detect similar triplicate elements..

Comment: @munir 1. for (i<n-2) 2. if (arr[i].intValue() == arr[i+1].intValue() && arr[i+1].intValue() == arr[i+2].intValue()) { triplicate } else { not triplicate }